# python 3.5 connect mysql 3.23

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I want to connect to mysql 3.23 database using python 3.5. I would like to ask which connector is available. Thanks.
I'm just starting to learn python. Please help me.
I can't load mysql-connector-python version 2

Successfully connected mysql 3.23 to python 3.5.

Comment: Do you seriously have a MySQL *3* database?! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Milestones There's literally no currently available official connector version that still supports that: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-versions.html

Comment: You can try https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1, but that doesn't support Python 3.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Install like this: `pip install mysql-connector-python`

Run like this:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="", user="", password="", database="", connection_timeout=240)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM table"

mycursor.execute(sql) 

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for result in myresult:
    print(result)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried and was unsuccessful.

File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 87      
    f"MySQL Connector/Python C Extension not available ({exc})"
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax